# How to translate mouse overs?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am using the field 'image' and have the 'alt' and 'title' options for the image. The 'title' shows on mouseover. How do I translate this? Or if it isn't translatable how can I show another field that is translatable as the mouse over?

Comment: **Where** you are using this field? If you translate content, you usually are supposed to create a brand new node for each language, with it's own image files and their texts, so this shouldn't be ever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title mouse-over is translatable. I needed to enable the content type-> edit -> publishing options -> multilingual settings and it works.